# Geolocation in Windows Universal App 10

Tags: c#, windows, geolocation

I am trying to get the geolocation of my device like this:

```
        Geolocator geo = new Geolocator();
        double lat = 0, longt = 0;

        Task getPosition = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                Geoposition pos = await geo.GetGeopositionAsync();
                lat = pos.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude;
                longt = pos.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude;
            }
            catch(Exception exp)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(exp);
            }

        });
        getPosition.Wait();
```

But, I'm getting the following exception:

> Your App does not have permission to access location data. Make sure
>   you have defined ID_CAP_LOCATION in the application manifest and that
>   on your phone, you have turned on location by checking Settings >
>   Location.

- Testing on my laptop with Windows 10
- Location is activated on my laptop
- I added Location capability in the manifest

Any idea of what could be the problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned laptop, but the error message is for a phone. Are you running this in the phone's emulator and have you turned it on in your phone?  IF not just turn it on in Settings-> Location. If not, send me the project adamt at microsoft and I'll duplicate and fix and post update here or try to duplicate on my end.

---

Edit - I've seen the project
Solution:
You need to include Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync() from Windows 10 onwards. This will prompt the user to allow the location request. IN your specific example ensure you mark you button1_click with async:

```
  private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br225537.aspx

```
var accessStatus = await Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync();
switch (accessStatus)
{
    case GeolocationAccessStatus.Allowed:
        _rootPage.NotifyUser("Waiting for update...", NotifyType.StatusMessage);

        // If DesiredAccuracy or DesiredAccuracyInMeters are not set (or value is 0), DesiredAccuracy.Default is used.
        Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator { DesiredAccuracyInMeters = _desireAccuracyInMetersValue };

        // Subscribe to StatusChanged event to get updates of location status changes
        _geolocator.StatusChanged += OnStatusChanged;

        // Carry out the operation
        Geoposition pos = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();

        UpdateLocationData(pos);
        _rootPage.NotifyUser("Location updated.", NotifyType.StatusMessage);
        break;

    case GeolocationAccessStatus.Denied:
        _rootPage.NotifyUser("Access to location is denied.", NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
        LocationDisabledMessage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        UpdateLocationData(null);
        break;

    case GeolocationAccessStatus.Unspecified:
        _rootPage.NotifyUser("Unspecified error.", NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
        UpdateLocationData(null);
        break;
}
```

Comment: I'm running the project as Local Machine, not emulator. How can I send you the project? Thanks!

Comment: email me a zip to adamt at microsoft

Comment: Ok, I've sent you the project to adamt at microsoft .com Let me know if you received it. Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! I have just one doubt about the code. Can you explain me the OnStatusChanged? It doesn't seem to exist a variable with that name, and I don't know what's the purpose.

Comment: thats an event handler to get notified when the status changes. If you type _geolocator.StatusChange+= I believe then TAB you'll create the event handler automatically. Its optional just to get notified of changes, you can comment it out if youd like

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't used to setting handlers that way.

Comment: What if the user has deactivated location? Will the application crash? How should this be avoided?